# Referencing outer SelectMany parameter from inner Select

Tags: linq, c#-3.0

I thought I had got this to work before, but I just don't see it:

discounts is a `Dictionary<PartType, double>`.  data is a `List<PartType>`.

```
var d = discounts.Keys.SelectMany(
    k =>
    data.Where( l => l.PartTypeID.Equals( k.PartTypeID ) ) )
    .Select( s => new { k, l } );
```

The error is, the name 'k' (and 'l') does not exist in the current context.

What I eventually want to do is apply the `double` from the dictionary to all the matching PartTypes in data.

Comment: What do you mean by 'apply'? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: By apply, I mean that PartType has a property, DiscountPercent, that I want to set to the value from the Dictionary.  But my real problem is that new{k,l} or {k,s} as @Yuriy noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you mean:

```
var d = discounts.Keys.SelectMany(
    k => data.Where(l => l.PartTypeID.Equals(k.PartTypeID)),
    (k, l) => new { k, l });
```

... but it's hard to tell without more information. To be honest it *looks* like you really want a join, e.g.

```
var d = discounts.Keys.Join(data,
           k => k.PartTypeID, // Key from discounts.Keys
           l => l.PartTypeID, // Key from data
           (k, l) => new { k, l }); // Projection from the two values
```

Comment: you are right on both counts, but in another app, I have something like this that seems to work:

Comment: (Oops, took too long getting that comment edited) - it was my extra parenthesis before .Select that I wasn't seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The `l` is in the context of the lambda in the `Where`. I think you mean `s => new {k, s}`. Also your parentheses seem wrong. That last parentheses on line 3 should be on line 4.

Comment: Right you are, but 'k' still seems to be out of scope.

Comment: @Kelly the parentheses change should fix that.

Comment: @Kelly: You've got one too many brackets for it to still be in scope, but it's not clear what you're trying to do in the first place.